# Condition supplied in cron job returns "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, cron, redhat

I am attempting to execute this code in a cron job:

```
a=`/home/mailmark/node/bin/forever list`; if [ "$a" == "No forever processes running" ]; then forever start /api.js; fi
```

The file in question, 'forever' contains this shebang:

```
#!usr/bin/env node
```

It returns this response:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

But I have this code on the last line of the .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=/home/mailmark/node/bin:$PATH
```

What should I do to make my cron work?

Answer (score 4):

Use the full path to node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/mailmark/node/bin/node
```

Answer (score 3):

`cron` doesn't run in a "login shell", so `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` are not loaded.

Comment: And how to fix on mac os x? There is no .bashrc or .bash_profile :(

Answer (score 1):

add `. $HOME/.bashrc` to the beginning of your cron job.